# convert bash pipeline into a function with parameter

Tags: bash

I have a pipeline I use to preview csv files:

`cat file_name.csv | sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' | column -t -s ","| less -s`

But i want to create an alias `viewcsv` that will allow to just replace the filename.

I tried `viewcsv="cat $1 | sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' | column -t -s ","| less -s"` but that didn't work.  Googling turned up that I need to convert this pipeline to a function?  How can i convert this to a function so that `viewcsv file_name.csv` will return same output as `cat file_name.csv | sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' | column -t -s ","| less -s` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function syntax looks like this:

```sh
viewcsv() {
    sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' "$1" | column -t -s ","| less -s
}
```

Notice that I have replaced `cat "$1" | sed` with `sed "$1"`.

[csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has a CSV previewer, by the way:

```
$ csvlook <<< $'a,b,c\n10,20,30'
|  a |  b |  c |
| -- | -- | -- |
| 10 | 20 | 30 |
```

Comment: I think the problem is that "$1" is still in the pipline, so it is not working...

Comment: @yulGM It definitely works for me, do you maybe still have an alias defined with that name somewhere?

Comment: I changed it to ```function viewcsv {
    sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' "$1" | column -t -s ","| less -s
}``` and put it in .bash_profile.  it seems working now. Thanks!

Comment: @yulGM: Please show output of `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: @Cyrus `/bin/bash`